# Problem installing MySQL

Tags: 14.04, mysql

I am trying to install the compiled mysql by others, in the process, I only need to offer the parameter（such as port ,datadir）,but after I enter the third parameter ,the system become unreadable. What should I do to solve the problem?

```
root@test:~$ ./mysql-inst 
-e 
***Deploy mysql server ...

-e The mysql server data directory is /root/test/mysql/mydata, continue?(y/n): y
-e The mysql server log-bin directory is /root/test/mysql/mylog, continue?(y/n): y
-e 
*Create mysql server directory ...

-e *MYSQL Tools confirm ...
-e Please input mysql toolkit tool directory(If not installed press enter): /root/test/percona-toolkit-2.4.12
-e *Setup profile ...
/tmp/.++-1815: 166: /++-/.++-1815: _-+_ce: +-+ f-++d
-e *Se++- --_+ ...
-e P+ea_e i+-++ +y_-+ _e_+e_ --_+: 
-e P+ea_e i+-++ +y_-+ _e_+e_ --_+: 
-e P+ea_e i+-++ +y_-+ _e_+e_ --_+: 
-e P+ea_e i+-++ +y_-+ _e_+e_ --_+:
```

Answer (score 0):

The default userID of the mysql server is mysql.  Once the running server as become it's effective uid it will loose access to the folders under /root.  You would have to put your data in a different folder, not /root.

Installed of having your area `/root/test/mysql` either create your own directory such as `/myown/test/mysql`.  Or you could put it in one of the directories already in the system such as `/lib/test/mysql`.